# Combine 2 dataframes of unequal length based on some condition

Tags: pandas

I have 2 dataframes e.g.:

```
df1 = [id, name, salary, address, address_if_present_in_US]
df2 = [id, name, salary,address]
```

I would like to add a new field to `df2` that says 'final_check', which will have Yes or No.

Case1-TRUE: Wherever the id in `df2` is not present in `df1` or if present, `address_if_present_in_US` field should have `FALSE` value.

Case2-FALSE: If not satisfied in case-1, then `FALSE`.

Kindly let me know how to do vlookup on ID where `address_if_present_in_US` should be equal to `FALSE`.

If I take an example, **df1**:

| id | name | salary | address | address_if_present_in_US |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | User1 | 10000 | US | TRUE |
| 234 | User2 | 20000 | UK | FALSE |
| 689 | User4 | 25000 | RUSSIA | FALSE |

**df2**:

| id | name | salary | address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | User1 | 10000 | US |
| 234 | User2 | 20000 | UK |
| 509 | User 3 | 30000 | EGYPT |

**Final Output**:

| id | name | salary | address | final_check |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | User1 | 10 | US | Yes/True |
| 234 | User2 | 20 | UK | No/False |
| 509 | User3 | 30 | EGYPT | No/False {Not Present} |

Comment: If you want to perform a lookup try looking into the [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) methods.

Comment: vlookup with a where clause. Is it possible using merge or join?

Comment: You can just filter the table down to the rows where `address_if_present_in_US == False` before performing the lookup.

Comment: Filtering first might not help here. Attached an example for reference with the question

Comment: Filtering it first should work, if it's a simply true/false you would not even need to use `merge` or `join`, but can simply use the `isin` method: `df2["id"].isin(df1.loc[~df1["address_if_present_in_US"], "id"])`.

Comment: Filtering will give us final_check value as No for id = 123 because after filtering (address_if_present_in_US == False ) , id = 123 will not be present in df1. Hence, as per Case1 scenario, as id=123 isnt present, so final_check will become No. But, I expect it to be Yes.

Comment: thanks Oxbowerce and Udaya for reaching out.

Answer (score 1):

```
df2['final_check']= df2.apply(lambda x : 'Yes/True' if(x['address'] in list((df.query("address_if_present_in_US==True"))['address'])) else 'No/False',axis=1)
```